# Read not correct JSON

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have JSON as string

```
"{nameBitsCount=131}"
```

I need, using Jackson: 1) Parse this JSON correctly. 2) Put result into Map<String, Long>

But I Getting exception.

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('n' (code 110)): was expecting double-quote to start field name
 at [Source: (String)"{nameBitsCount=131}";
```

PS: I think I need to change style of JSON to this

```
"{\"nameBitsCount\":\"131\"}";
```

Comment: This isn't valid JSON. May be you want: "{ "nameBitsCount": 131 }"

Answer (score 0):

The JSON you send isn't valid

```
{nameBitsCount=131}
```

need to convert format :

```
{"nameBitsCount":131}
```

add {"} around the Key and change {=} to {:} the JSON format valid for Json Object :

```
{
"Key" : "Value" 
// "VALUE" if use for String and char put {"} around the value VALUE ex: 0.0 , 1 , -50 , FALSE
}
```

Look this website :
[JSON Website](https://www.json.org/json-en.html)

[JSON Syntax](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_syntax.asp)